# Android : Capturing image in a background service CAUSES ISSUES

Tags: android, android-service

the problem I am facing is this :
    1) I strictly want to capture image and video from android background service (and NOT FROM ACTIVITY).
    2) Now the issues are : 
         a) In devices like Samsung galaxy s6 edge, image is taken first time correctly and almost immediately after firing service. But second time onwards it hangs. And it has become quite difficult to track Exception from console even after trying a lot.
         b)In devices like Nexus 6, after service fired, it takes  lot of time to start process of capturing image and sometimes not capturing at all.

c) Now the worst part is , even if it captures image after delays, it freezes the phone totally and not just the screen. If only screen was frozen, it could be understood, because a 1 X 1 surfaceview was drawn (else android wont allow to take image). Anyways, here I am posting code. Any help will be appreciated:

The main service (CamerService.java):
                   public class CamerService extends Service implements
                        SurfaceHolder.Callback {

```
                private Camera mCamera;

                private Camera.Parameters parameters;
                private Bitmap bmp;
                FileOutputStream fo;
                private String FLASH_MODE;
                private int QUALITY_MODE = 0;
                private boolean isFrontCamRequest = false;
                private Camera.Size pictureSize;
                SurfaceView sv;
                private SurfaceHolder sHolder;
                private WindowManager windowManager;
                WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
                public Intent cameraIntent;
                SharedPreferences pref;
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
                int width = 0, height = 0;


                @Override
                public void onCreate() {
                    super.onCreate();
                }


                Handler handler = new Handler();
  Image capture asynctask :

                private class TakeImage extends AsyncTask<Intent, Void, Void> {
.
.
.
.
private synchronized void takeImage(Intent intent) {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            try {
                                if (mCamera != null) {
                                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                                    mCamera.release();
                                    mCamera = null;
                                }
                                if (sv != null)
                                    windowManager.removeView(sv);

                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },2000);
                    if (checkCameraHardware(getApplicationContext())) {
                        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                        if (extras != null) {
                            String flash_mode = extras.getString("FLASH");
                            FLASH_MODE = flash_mode;

                            boolean front_cam_req = extras.getBoolean("Front_Request");
                            isFrontCamRequest = front_cam_req;

                            int quality_mode = extras.getInt("Quality_Mode");
                            QUALITY_MODE = quality_mode;
                        }
                        if (FLASH_MODE==null)
                        FLASH_MODE = "off";


                        if (isFrontCamRequest) {
                                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {

                                mCamera = openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();
                                if (mCamera != null) {

                                    try {
                                        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                        "API dosen't support front camera",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                        });

                                        stopSelf();
                                    }
                                    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                                    pictureSize = getBiggesttPictureSize(parameters);
                                    if (pictureSize != null)
                                        parameters
                                                .setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);

                                    // set camera parameters
                                    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                                    try
                                    {
                                        Thread.sleep(20);
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    mCamera.startPreview();
                                    mCamera.takePicture(mShutter, null, mCall);
                                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                                    mCamera.startPreview();
                                    // return 4;

                                } else {
                                    mCamera = null;
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "Your Device dosen't have Front Camera !",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    });

                                    stopSelf();
                                }

                            } else {
                                if (checkFrontCamera(getApplicationContext())) {
                                    mCamera = openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();

                                    if (mCamera != null) {

                                        try {
                                            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    Toast.makeText(
                                                            getApplicationContext(),
                                                            "API dosen't support front camera",
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }
                                            });

                                            stopSelf();
                                        }
                                        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                                        pictureSize = getBiggesttPictureSize(parameters);
                                        if (pictureSize != null)
                                            parameters
                                                    .setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);

                                        // set camera parameters
                                        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                                        try
                                        {
                                            Thread.sleep(20);
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception e)
                                        {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        mCamera.startPreview();
                                        ///.setPreviewCallback(null);

                                        mCamera.takePicture(mShutter, null, mCall);
                                        mCamera.stopPreview();
                                        mCamera.startPreview();
                                        // return 4;

                                    } else {
                                        mCamera = null;

                                        handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {


                                            }
                                        });

                                        stopSelf();

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }

                        else // backcam
                            {

                            if (mCamera != null) {
                                mCamera.stopPreview();
                                mCamera.release();
                                mCamera = Camera.open();
                            } else
                                mCamera = getCameraInstance();

                            try {
                                if (mCamera != null) {
                                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sv.getHolder());
                                    parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                                    if (FLASH_MODE == null || FLASH_MODE.isEmpty()) {
                                        FLASH_MODE = "auto";
                                    }
                                    parameters.setFlashMode(FLASH_MODE);
                                    // set biggest picture
                                    setBesttPictureResolution();
                                    // log quality and image format
                                    Log.d("Qaulity", parameters.getJpegQuality() + "");
                                    Log.d("Format", parameters.getPictureFormat() + "");

                                    // set camera parameters
                                    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                                    try
                                    {
                                        Thread.sleep(20);
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    mCamera.startPreview();
                                    Log.d("ImageTakin", "OnTake()");
                                    //mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                                    mCamera.takePicture(mShutter, null, mCall);
                                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                                    mCamera.startPreview();
                                } else {
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            try {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                        "Camera is unavailable !",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                         catch (Exception e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            Log.e("TAG", "CmaraHeadService()::takePicture", e);
                                            NotiUtils.sendNot3(getApplicationContext(),"err1001",""+e,4);
                                            stopSelf();
                                        }
                                        }
                                    });
            stopSelf();
                                }
                                // return 4;

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                Log.e("TAG", "CmaraHeadService()::takePicture", e);
                                NotiUtils.sendNot3(getApplicationContext(),"err",""+e,4);
                                stopSelf();
                            }
                            }

                    } else {
                        // display in long period of time

                        try {
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Your Device dosen't have a Camera !",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            NotiUtils.sendNot3(getApplicationContext(),"err2002",""+e,4);
                            stopSelf();
                        }
                        stopSelf();
                    }

                    // return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

                }

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

         cameraIntent = intent;
                    Log.d("ImageTakin", "StartCommand()");
                    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
                    editor = pref.edit();
            try {
                windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

                params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
                );
                params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
                params.width = 1;
                params.height = 1;
                params.x = 0;
                params.y = 0;
                sv = new SurfaceView(getApplicationContext());

                windowManager.addView(sv, params);
                sHolder = sv.getHolder();
                sHolder.addCallback(this);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
                    sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                    return START_NOT_STICKY;
                }
            String file;
                Camera.ShutterCallback mShutter ;
                        Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                        // decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap
                        Log.d("ImageTakin", "Done");
                        try {
                            if (bmp != null)
                                bmp.recycle();
                            System.gc();
                            bmp = decodeBitmap(data);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            if (bmp != null && QUALITY_MODE == 0)
                                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bytes);
                            else if (bmp != null && QUALITY_MODE != 0)
                                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, QUALITY_MODE, bytes);
            //


                            try {
                                if (mCamera != null) {
                                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                                    mCamera.release();
                                    mCamera = null;
                                }
                                if (sv != null)
                                    windowManager.removeView(sv);

                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            File imagesFolder = new File(
                                    Constants.CAMERSERV_STOR);
                            if (!imagesFolder.exists())
                                imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
                            File image = new File(imagesFolder, System.currentTimeMillis()
                                    + ".jpg");
            file=image.getAbsolutePath();

                            try {
                                fo = new FileOutputStream(image);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("TAG", "FileNotFoundException", e);
            stopSelf();
                            }
                            try {
                                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
            stopSelf();
                            }
                                        try {
                                fo.close();
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
                                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                                            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                                            Uri.parse("file://"
                                                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                                else {
                                    MediaScannerConnection
                                            .scanFile(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    new String[]{image.toString()},
                                                    null,
                                                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                                        public void onScanCompleted(
                                                                String path, Uri uri) {


                                                        }
                                                    });
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                NotiUtils.sendNot3(getApplicationContext(),"err303",""+e,4);
            stopSelf();
                            }
                            if (mCamera != null) {
                                mCamera.stopPreview();
                                mCamera.release();
                                mCamera = null;
                            }


                            Log.d("Camera", "Image Taken !");
                            if (bmp != null) {
                                bmp.recycle();
                                bmp = null;
                                System.gc();
                            }
                            mCamera = null;
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                "Your Picture has been taken !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                .show();
                                    }
                                    catch(Exception e)
                                    {

                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        NotiUtils.sendNot3(getApplicationContext(),"err5051",""+e,4);
                                        stopSelf();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            count++;
            Log.e("excecamrServ",":count:"+count);
                            Intent ii=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UploadMedia.class);
                            ii.putExtra("file",""+file);
                            ii.setAction("foo");
                            if (isFrontCamRequest)
                            ii.putExtra("type","frontCam");
                            else

                            ii.putExtra("type","backCam");
                            ii.putExtra("type2","img1");
                            if (Helper.isMyServiceRunning(getApplicationContext(),UploadMedia.class))
                            stopService(ii);

               stopSelf();
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

            stopSelf();
                        }
                    }
                };
            int count=0;
                @Override
                public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                    return null;
                }

                public  Camera getCameraInstance() {
                    Camera c = null;
                    try {
                        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
```

stopSelf();
                        }
                        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
                    }

```
                @Override
                public void onDestroy() {
                    try {
                        if (mCamera != null) {
                            mCamera.stopPreview();
                            mCamera.release();
                            mCamera = null;
                        }
                        if (sv != null)
                            windowManager.removeView(sv);
                        Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");

                        intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
                 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    super.onDestroy();
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                                           int height) {

                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    if (cameraIntent != null)
                        new TakeImage().execute(cameraIntent);

                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    try {
                        if (mCamera != null) {
                            mCamera.stopPreview();
                            mCamera.release();
                            mCamera = null;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        stopSelf();
                    }
                }
```

NOW, this is how the Service is started :

```
            Intent front_translucent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CamerService.class);

            front_translucent.putExtra("Quality_Mode",  30);
            //Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
             front_translucent.putExtra("Front_Request", false);
             front_translucent.putExtra("FLASH", "on");

            //Log.e("info",";"+info.canDisableShutterSound);
        startService(front_translucent);
```

Please help finding out reason for delays or failures or freezing of screen

Comment: Are there any relevant logs in ADB?

Comment: Nope. Cant be tracked. If error directly got caught by a catch block somewhere , then logs would have shown stack trace, but here none of the catch blocks seem to catch the exception.

Comment: Are there any device related ADB logs? If the entire device is freezing I'm imagining that the bugs wont be related to your code. Instead the OS might start throwing errors or warnings that could indicate some of the issues.